# Entity Framework Core code-first many-to-many properties in join table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I have 3 tables: `Documents`, `Products` and `Items` which is the join table with `Quantity` and `Price`.

It looks something like this (simplified):

```cs
public class Document 
{
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; } = new();
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Product 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Items> Items { get; set; } = new(); 
    public List<Document> Documents { get; set; } = new();
}

public class Items 
{
    public Document Document { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

It is joined with this:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Document>()
    .HasMany(p => p.Products)
    .WithMany(p => p.Documents)
    .UsingEntity<Items>();
```

And it works, but I have the following problem: result is object with separated properties

```cs
doc.Products[0].Name
doc.Items[0].Quantity
doc.Items[0].Price
```

Or:

```cs
doc.Items[0].Product.Name
doc.Items[0].Quantity
doc.Items[0].Price
```

How can I get:

```cs
doc.Products[0].Name
doc.Products[0].Quantity
doc.Products[0].Price
```

> Many hours later:
>
> After a some research I found out that properties in join table is
> called `payload`.
>
> Also EF has a so-called thing `skip navigations` so you can skip join
> table in model use (which is applied to the example above). For example, instead of using `document.items.products`,
> you can use just `document.products`.
>
> But, problem is when join have payload. Then the data is in two
> places. For example, if you need product name and price, that is
> `document.product.name` and `document.item.price`.
>
> Yes, I know, it's the same in the database, however, I was hoping that
> if the EF already skipped the join table when using it, why isn't
> there some way to handle the payload (with Fluent Api or Data Annotations attributes). It can be called `skip payload` or `childernise payload`
> ;)
>
> Good article for this is:
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use SelectMany which flatten a multidimensional array by one level.

```
            Document doc = new Document();

            var results = doc.Products.SelectMany(x => x.Items.Select(y => new { name = x.Name, quant = y.Quantity, price = y.Price })).ToList();
```

If you want only the first then use this :

```
var results = doc.Products.Select(x => x.Items.Select(y => new { name = x.Name, quant = y.Quantity, price = y.Price }).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Yes, that's clear, but I'd like to flatten the object at design time, not at runtime. The point is to map the fields well. When it is inconsistent like this, it is not only a complication for reading, but also the add/change is messy.

Comment: You have a model and the model has to match the database tables.  So modifying to flatten would mean to modify the database.  To reduce runtime it may be better to flatten with my code and create a dictionary.

Comment: I'm confused (or dumb) but what is the DB tables and DB relationships actually supposed to look like (in the database - table defs and foreign key defs)?

Comment: The reason for multiple tables in a database is to reduce the amount of memory be removing duplicate information.  You can put all the data in one table but then the Product name would be repeated multiple times.  So when you design a database there is a tradeoff of time (which is needed to do a join) verses amount of memory used.  Foreign keys are used to join tables.  A database can be many different views.  You have to choose the view that is best for your application based on memory size and time to access the data.  Time will increase when you do joins.